# How to fit a model to my binary time series data using R?

Tags: r, time-series, logistic, classification, autoregressive

### Problem

I have a binary time series with a binary dependent variable and several independent variables. What are some appropriate and easy to understand approaches using R that I haven't thought of?

I have provided an example to illustrate the issues I am having in analyzing this kind of problem. Please read below in details.

### Details

My question pivots on the fact that my dataset is binary and a time series. My simulated data here is simple and the experimental design is bad, but please ignore that and focus on understanding the data. Imagine the following scenario to illustrate my situation.

- Individual asked to walk on a hiking trail.
- The trail is divided into 6 zones. The zones 0, 1,3, and 5 are easy and they can walk without issues, but zone 2 and 4 are expected to cause significant fatigue due to features like high gradient and etc.
- At the end of the trail, each participant rated how tired they were on the trail in each zone on a scale of 1 to 7. 1 is rested and 7 is completely fatigued
- Their heart rate was recorded at regular intervals during the hike. For example, there are ten heart rate values recorded while they were in zone q0.
- An expert annotated the data with fatigue, 0 being no fatigue and 1 being fatigue. This is our dependent variable

In summary, I have a binary independent variable fatigue. How can I fit a model to explain fatigue given zones, rating, heart_rate, and participant?

### CODE

I have simulated data to demonstrate my problem. My real data is much larger and actually converges for logistic regression and glmmPQL, but the methods don't converge for the simulated data below.

```
#Step 0: Simulate the data 

#y is our independent variable. zones, ratings, hr, and participants are our dependent variables 
y <- c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)
zones<-c("q0","q0", "q0","q0","q0","q0","q0", "q0","q0","q0","q1","q1","q1","q1","q1","q1","q1","q1","q1","q1","q2","q2","q2","q2","q2","q2","q2","q2","q2","q2","q3","q3","q3","q3","q3","q3","q3","q3","q3","q3","q4","q4","q4","q4","q4","q4","q4","q4","q4","q4","q5","q5","q5","q5","q5","q5","q5","q5","q5","q5","q0","q0", "q0","q0","q0","q0","q0", "q0","q0","q0","q1","q1","q1","q1","q1","q1","q1","q1","q1","q1","q2","q2","q2","q2","q2","q2","q2","q2","q2","q2","q3","q3","q3","q3","q3","q3","q3","q3","q3","q3","q4","q4","q4","q4","q4","q4","q4","q4","q4","q4","q5","q5","q5","q5","q5","q5","q5","q5","q5","q5")
ratings <- c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2)
heart_rate <- c(76.42, 76.4, 76.4, 76.43, 76.5, 76.55, 76.62, 76.67, 76.72, 76.73, 95.27, 95.55, 95.87, 96.15, 96.43, 96.73, 97, 97.17, 97.33, 97.33, 107.52, 107.55, 107.57, 107.62, 107.67, 107.78, 107.92, 108.08, 108.25, 108.35, 76.42, 76.4, 76.4, 76.43, 76.5, 76.55, 76.62, 76.67, 76.72, 76.73, 108.52, 108.55, 108.57, 108.62, 108.67, 108.78, 108.92, 108.08, 108.25, 108.35, 75.42, 75.4, 75.4, 75.43, 75.5, 75.55, 75.62, 75.67, 75.72, 75.73, 78.42, 78.4, 78.4, 78.43, 78.5, 78.55, 78.62, 78.67, 78.72, 78.73, 98.27, 99.55, 99.87, 99.15, 99.43, 99.73, 99, 99.17, 99.33, 99.33, 109.52, 109.55, 109.57, 109.62, 109.67, 109.78, 109.92, 109.08, 109.25, 109.35, 96.42, 96.4, 96.4, 96.43, 96.5, 96.55, 96.62, 96.67, 96.72, 96.73, 107.52, 107.55, 107.57, 108.62, 109.67, 110.78, 110.92, 110.08, 110.25, 110.35, 85.42, 85.4, 85.4, 85.43, 85.5, 85.55, 85.62, 85.67, 85.72, 85.73)
participant <- c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2)


#Step 0.1 Create the dataframe 
data_set=cbind(y,zones,ratings,heart_rate, participant)
columns = c("fatigue", "zones", "ratings","heart_rate","participant")
train_set = as.data.frame(data_set)
colnames(train_set) <- columns


#Step 0.2: Refactor variables to be appropriate for logistic and linear models 
#Refactor the levels of zones to 0, 1, 2, ...., 13
levels(train_set$zones) <- c(0,1,2,3,4,5)
levels(train_set$ratings) <- c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7)
levels(train_set$participant) <- c(1, 2)

#Step 1: Analysis 

#Logistic 
fit <- glm(fatigue ~ zones + ratings + heart_rate + participant, family = binomial(link = "logit"), data = train_set) #Doesn't converge 


#GLMPQL 
library(MASS)
library(nlme)

model <- glmmPQL(fatigue ~ zones + ratings + heart_rate + participant, data = train_set, family = binomial, random = ~1 | zones, correlation = corAR1(form = ~1 | zones)) #Doesn't converge
```

For my analysis, a couple of things to keep in mind. Please note:

- I used regular logistic regression, but it is temporal and does not take into account that I probably have serial correlation (means I have a time series and data observations aren't independent) here.
- I used GLMM PQL because it uses logistic and AR features. However, I would appreciate critique of how I am implementing it because I got bad results (accuracy was 40% when I did training with the models with cross validation) using my real data and feel there must be a better way to build a model?

I am not convinced I am using the appropriate methods to analyze this kind of data and as a result getting bad results. Since my data is temporal and a time series, I was hoping there is some sort of hybrid logistic ARMA/General linear model approach that could assist me, but I don't know about.

Any suggestions, comments, or ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Don't know if this matters, but you don't seem to have any "ratings" of "4" in your example data.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out, in my actual data, I think sample size is sufficiently large to guarantee that I see all responses 1 - 7 for ratings.